# Added a new column to my table in my RoR application, but unable to add details in that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Im a newbie in Ruby on Rails, im practicing to work with it.. i had created an application using `rails generate controller activity list add edit delete` and `rails generate model activity name:string summary:text` and worked well..

But when i added a column to the table newapp using sqlite3 and tried to add new record.. everyhting is working fine.. no errors but date is not saved.. why is this happening? i think it may be a very small problem but im working on thins since 3 hours and couldn't figured it out.. any help is appreciated

This is the code of my controller

```
def create
@activity_detail = Activity.new(activity_detail_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @activity_detail.save
    format.html { redirect_to activity_new_path, notice: 'Activity details were successfully saved.' }
    format.json { render :view, status: :created, location: @activity_detail }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @activity_detail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

`def activity_detail_params
      params.require(:activity).permit(:name, :summary, :dated)
end`

(I added :date after the modification of my table)

my view code

```
  <%= form_for :activity, url: activity_create_url do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %> *  <%= f.text_field :name , class: "text" %>
    </div>
    <span id="title-err"></span>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :date %> *  <%= f.text_field :dated , class: "text" %>
    </div><span id="date-err"></span>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :summary %> <%= f.text_area :summary , class: "text" %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', activity_view_path, class:"link" %>  <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Server log

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png" for 127.0.0.1 at
 2014-07-24 16:34:34 +0530    
 Started POST "/activity/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-24 16:34:42
 +0530 Processing by ActivityController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√",    "authenticity_token"=>"1WrRLrAEdga7IiZzf11hec2dv/yzs
 +Qq//Q3U9B9urw=", "activity"=>{"name"=>"new", "dated"=>"07/23/2014", "summary"=> "asf"}, "commit"=>"Save Activity"} Unpermitted parameters:
 dated    (0.0ms)  begin transaction   SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO
 "activities" ("created_at", "name", "summary", "updat ed_at") VALUES
 (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-07-24 11:04:42.671875"], ["na me",
 "new"], ["summary", "asf"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-24
 11:04:42.671875"]]    (156.3ms)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: ok.. i have added code to my question..

Comment: Can you post your `view code`?

Comment: Check the above code please..

Comment: Try changing this line `<%= form_for :activity, url: activity_create_url do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for @activity_detail, url: activity_create_url do |f| %>` might work i guess.

Comment: changed but.. no luck :(

Comment: Hmm,Can you post the `server log` generated? It should give us a clear idea about what is happening.

Comment: Your code is in production mode? If so,did you restarted the server after you made the changes to the code?

Comment: I think that's what you asked for.. and i have restarted my server

Comment: Your log shows that the field name is `dated`.Have you migrated it as `date` or `dated`?

Comment: its dated.. i have changed it in the view and controller

Comment: no.. it's behaving like the dated field doesnt even exist.. working for name and summary.. but not for dated

Comment: If you have migrated it as `dated`,then you have to change the `date` in `view code` and in `controller code` to `dated`.

Comment: i did and restarted server after that.. still not working..

Comment: Have you restarted your server after that?

Comment: i dont understand why its not mentioning dated while insertion in server log.. please tell me why @Pavan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was fine in my code.. the problem was i didnt know that Ruby is so perticular about date format. When i gave the format as `yyyy-mm-dd` worked fine for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed the following steps:

```
rails g migration AddDateToActivity
```

Then open that file add column:

```
add_column :activities, :date, :date
```

Then through console:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Restart your server

**Edit**

To make sure changes goto `rails console` and see the result of

```
Activity.column_names
```

Comment: Yeah. I did, and the column is successfully added.. but i cant save anything in that column from browser. Where as i can add data to other columns..

Comment: its working i can view also dates if i add from console.. in my list page.. but cant add from the browser

Answer (score 0):

"Date" is a reserved word in Rails, so maybe it is conflicting with some function. Try a different name for that attribute. It would have been a bad name anyway, from a documentation point of view.